# How to make one subplot image larger with imgshow, to align two images?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a subplot of images and want to make the image on the left slightly larger, so that the axes line up. How can I do this?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img1 = mpimg.imread('../Reproducibility_Paper_Figures/noord_graph_image.png')
img2 = mpimg.imread('../Reproducibility_Paper_Figures/full_comparison.png')


f = plt.figure(figsize=(28.0,20.0))
f.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(img2,interpolation='none')
plt.axis('off')
f.add_subplot(1,2, 2)
plt.imshow(img1,interpolation='none')
plt.axis('off')
#plt.show(block=True)

f.tight_layout(pad=-5)
plt.savefig('../Reproducibility_Paper_Figures/side.png')
```

The images look like:

[image: the images]

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the desired alignment, is to explicit set extents to the images. The extents would be the axes of the data. And then use `sharey=True` to get both aligned. If the axes provide useful information, leave them visible, otherwise turn them off. In the demo code, all ticks are shown to help find the correct values for the extent.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img1 = mpimg.imread('image1.png')
img2 = mpimg.imread('image2.png')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize=(12.0, 5.0), ncols=2, sharey=True)

ax1.imshow(img2, interpolation='bilinear', extent=[0, 120, -21, 360], aspect=1/4)
# ax1.axis('off')
ax1.tick_params(labeltop=True, labelbottom=True, labelright=True, labelleft=True,
                top=True, bottom=True, right=True, left=True)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(20))
ax2.imshow(img1, interpolation='bilinear', extent=[0, 120, -37.5, 361], aspect=1/4)
ax2.axis('on')
ax2.tick_params(labeltop=True, labelbottom=True, labelright=True, labelleft=True,
                top=True, bottom=True, right=True, left=True)
# ax2.axis('off')
# plt.savefig('../Reproducibility_Paper_Figures/side.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting images]

PS: If you want to use `savefig` and `show` together, make sure that savefig is called first. `plt.show` will erase the image.